# Disable Print("") In Swift 4, Xcode 10

Tags: swift

I have Tried Many of Code But Could not disable Print() in Swift 4.
Can it can be disable?
Thanks

```
func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {

    #if DEBUG

    var idx = items.startIndex
    let endIdx = items.endIndex

    repeat {
        Swift.print(items[idx], separator: separator, terminator: idx == (endIdx - 1) ? terminator : separator)
        idx += 1
    }
    while idx < endIdx

    #endif
}
```

Comment: Just dont call it ‍♂️ but seriously, what is the problem?

Comment: just change the scope to public

Comment: but print() is still work

Answer (score 0):

Code wise it's working as expected, your problem probably lies somewhere else,

and i think it's the scope of the function, Swift functions are declared with `internal` access modifier by default, you can try to change the position of this function into a separated file, calling it `PublicUtility.swift` for example.

and place your function there with access modifier `public` so would it be like this .

```
public func print(items: Any..., separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {

#if DEBUG

var idx = items.startIndex
let endIdx = items.endIndex

repeat {
    Swift.print(items[idx], separator: separator, terminator: idx == (endIdx - 1) ? terminator : separator)
    idx += 1
}
while idx < endIdx

    #endif
}
```

> Note : if you're calling your function and not the `Swift.print`, the
>   color of it should be different, like you're calling your own function
>   not the default one.

Comment: Can you show how are you using it like where is the function placed and it’s access modifier

Comment: . just placed that in public class, but the console still print , what I have to do more, Do I have to call that in somewhere?

Comment: When you calling it the color of the function should indicate as custom and you should be building using debug mode not release mode double check that

Comment: how to call that., please tell me, and where to call that to disable all print in my project